# Why can't I see ~/Documents directory from command line? ( I could yesterday! )

Tags: command-line, permission

This morning I found I could not view the `~/Documents` directory, while I could yesterday, and I still can via Finder app.

```
stewart@M-V935Q9 ~ % cd
stewart@M-V935Q9 ~ % pwd
/Users/stewart
stewart@M-V935Q9 ~ % ls ~/Documents
ls: /Users/stewart/Documents: Operation not permitted
stewart@M-V935Q9 ~ % ls -l@e
total 8
drwx------@  4 stewart    staff   128  3 Nov 13:53 Applications
    com.apple.quarantine      21
drwx------   4 stewart    staff   128  1 Dec 10:18 Desktop
drwx------  16 stewart    staff   512  7 Dec 10:01 Documents
drwx------  17 stewart    staff   544  7 Dec 10:34 Downloads
drwx------@ 81 stewart    staff  2592 25 Nov 18:57 Library
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32
drwx------   4 stewart    staff   128  7 Nov 10:55 Movies
drwx------   3 stewart    staff    96  3 Nov 12:51 Music
drwx------   6 stewart    staff   192 18 Nov 12:52 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x   3 stewart    staff    96 25 Nov 18:44 Postman
drwxr-xr-x   4 stewart    staff   128  3 Nov 12:51 Public
```

What could possibly have changed?

Comment: What is your current directory? What does ls -l@e show?

Comment: @mmmmmm  I've added output of that command

Comment: Add Terminal to "Full Disk Access" in System Settings > Privacy/Security.

Comment: @benwiggy. This worked. If you would like to post as an actual answer, I'll accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like any other app, Terminal needs permission to access "the three Ds" - Desktop, Documents and Downloads.

Granting it Full Disk Access in System Settings/Preferences under Privacy & Security will fix it.

Why this changed from yesterday for you, I don't know.